# How can I verify if there is an incoming message to my node with MPI?

Tags: python, mpi

I'm doing a project using Python with MPI. Every node of my project needs to know if there is any incoming message for it before continuing the execution of other tasks.

I'm working on a system where multiple nodes executes some operations. Some nodes may need the outputs of another nodes and therefore needs to know if this output is available.

For illustration purposes, let's consider two nodes, A and B. A needs the output of B to execute it's task, but if the output is not available A needs to do some other tasks and then verify if B has send it's output again, in a loop. What I want to do is this verification of availability of output from B in A.

I made some research and found something about a method called probe, but don't understood neither found a usefull documentation about what it does or how to use. So, I don't know if it solves my problem.

The idea of what I want is ver simple: I just need to check if there is data to be received when I use the method "recv" of mpi4py. If there is something the code do some tasks, if there ins't the code do some other taks.

Comment: To really help you, we need more information about how your application works. In general, use `irecv` rather than `probe`.

Comment: Thanks, just gave a better explanation of the problem.

Comment: If you know the size of the message that might arrive, then `MPI_Irecv()` and `MPI_Test()` is a fit. Otherwise `MPI_Iprobe()` is what you need. MPI is a well defined standard and all subroutines are fully specified and documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>(elaborating on Gilles Gouaillardet's comment)</sub>

If you know you will eventually receive a message, but want to be able to run some computations while it is being prepared and sent, you want to use non-blocking receives, *not* `probe`.

Basically use `MPI_Irecv` to setup a receive request as soon as possible. If you want to know whether the message is ready yet, use `MPI_Test` to check the request.

This is much better than using probes, because you ensure that a receive buffer is ready as early as possible and the sender is not blocked, waiting for the receiver to see that there is a message and post the receive.

For the specific implementation you will have to consult the manual of the Python MPI wrapper you use. You might also find helpful information in the MPI standard itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's really helping me. I'm trying to use MPI_Test but it isn't doing the job as I expected. In the documentation it says that it returns True in case of completion of  a request, however when it returns True and I try tp use MPI_Wait to get the message sent it blocks my program. I'm I using it wrong?

Comment: A call to `MPI_Test` that returns `flag=true` completes the request - you don't need to, and should not, call `MPI_Wait` on that request anymore. You get the actual message from the buffer that you provided to `MPI_Irecv`. The specific handling with your python wrapper my differ.

Comment: Thanks. MPI itself has a lot of documentation for C/C++, but lacks of it for Python :/ I'm inspecting the bitbucket repository to verify how can I use a buffer with irecv(). It says there is an optional argument called "buf" where I can put my buffer. I'm using an object as a buffer and It always give me the error "TypeError: expected a writeable buffer object". Well, I think it's another problem, for another thread, right?

Comment: It was right to post a new question (which I just answered). Particularly my answer was for MPI in general as I did not know which python binding you use. My answer might have misled you a bit because the high-level interface of mpi4py works a bit differently. I can't help but agree that the mpi4py documentation is lacking alot...